# MVC View htmlAttribute not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Can I know why the htmlAttribute of my textbox not working? I'm using @Html.BeginForm and only the part Hyperlink not following the other.

Below is my code.

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
    @token

    <div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>StoreDetail</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.StoreId)


    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NoOfSeat, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NoOfSeat, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NoOfSeat, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Hyperlink", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBox("Hyperlink", ViewData["Hyperlink"], new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" } })
        </div>
    </div>
```

[Screenshot of the problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWA7W.png)

If I remove the

```
    new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" } })
```

it will result in same view like it is not functioning.

Comment: replace `new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" } }` with `new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" }`and check

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: @RajshekarReddy Its working! Thanks man. :D

Comment: @RajshekarReddy Do you want me put the answer or you want to do it?

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace your this syntax

```
new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" } }
```

with

```
 new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" }
```

The syntax you are using is supported for `EditorFor` Helper only **[New Features in ASP.NET MVC 5.1](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/releases/mvc51-release-notes#new-features)**.

[image]

Comment: It's not answer. he is asking why `'htmlAttributes` attributes is not working. as it is valid syntex in mvc 5