# TextAreaFor Not Working When Using HtmlAttributes Overload

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, textarea

For some reasons, when I set my TextAreaFor style properties specifically the width property, it is not working, what I mean is the width is not changing, and the Id is not changing as well:

```
 @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.AdminSetting.Style, new { htmlAttributes = new 
 { @class = "form-control", @style = "width: 100%;", @id = "HelloWorld" } })
```

But if I remove the word **htmlAttributes** and change it to this then it working fine. I really wonder why:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.AdminSetting.Style, 
new { @class = "form-control", @style = "width: 100%;", @id = "HelloWorld" })
```

Is there reason why my TextAreaFor **htmlAttributes** not working unless I remove my declaration of htmlAttributes and declare it like this?

```
 new { @class = "form-control", @style = "width: 100%;", @id = "HelloWorld" })
```

Instead of this?

```
new { htmlAttributes = new 
 { @class = "form-control", @style = "width: 100%;", @id = "HelloWorld" } })
```

I've check the documentation, and I am sure that I am using the correct overload.

Comment: htmlAttributes  this will work for EditorFor . please look at difference

Comment: Yes I believe this will work but not work TextAreaFor. This word htmlAttributes were part of the scaffolding template that generated from MVC5.

Comment: Yes it is working for EditorFor, I validated it. I wonder why not in TextAreaFor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try as shown below:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.AdminSetting.Style, 
    new { maxlength = 1000, @class = "form-control", @id = "HelloWorld" })
```

The helpers, `Html.TextAreaFor`, `Html.EditorFor`, `Html.DisplayFor` are unique in that they're what's referred to as "templated helpers". Instead of just spitting out some defined bit of `HTML`, they're capable of actually using views to determine what their output will be. These views are referred to as "editor templates" or "display templates", respectively. For more information please have a look at [Html.EditorFor and htmlAttributes](https://cpratt.co/html-editorfor-and-htmlattributes/).

Comment: Yes it will work. But try this one: new { htmlAttributes = new 
 { //same code here } }) and it will not.

Comment: @WillyDavidJr Could you pls have a look at [What is the “HTML attributes” parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37589076/what-is-the-html-attributes-parameter)?

Comment: I've checked it. But I didn't get the point why using new htmlattributes doesn't work but anonymous types work?

Answer (score 0):

Syntax:

```
new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @style = "width: 100%;", @id = "HelloWorld" } })
```

represents additional data for ViewData and can be used with `EditorFor`.

See:
[MVC View htmlAttribute not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41296946/mvc-view-htmlattribute-not-working/41297238#41297238)

[MSDN - EditorFor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.htmlhelpereditorextensions.editorfor?view=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_Rendering_HtmlHelperEditorExtensions_EditorFor__2_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_Rendering_IHtmlHelper___0__System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func___0___1___System_Object_)

[MSDN - TextAreaFor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.htmlhelperinputextensions.textareafor?view=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_Rendering_HtmlHelperInputExtensions_TextAreaFor__2_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_Rendering_IHtmlHelper___0__System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func___0___1___System_Object_)