# Html.EnumDropDownListFor is not setting html attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to display a dropdown list for an enum set with a css class and disabled attribute.

This in on a .Net Framework 4.6.2 project. I have tried setting the htmlAttribute parameter, like the documentation (and all blog posts) suggests, but the resulting html does not include the html attributes.

Code from the View:

```
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.FundingDataSource, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "disabled", @disabled = "disabled" })
```

Expected

```
<select id="FundingDataSource" name="FundingDataSource" class="disabled" disabled="disabled"> 
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="2">Option 2</option>
</select>
```

Actual Html:

```
<select id="FundingDataSource" name="FundingDataSource"> 
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="2">Option 2</option>
</select>
```

Any thoughts or suggestions on what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Similar to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50648960/3923163), try removing the word `htmlAttributes` instead:

```
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.FundingDataSource, new { @class = "disabled", @disabled = "disabled" })
```